# Generate complex XML with T-SQL syntax

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a query that would return more or less complex XML structure. This is expected output I would like to have:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: some_messageID</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">ServiceURL</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
                 <HereRouteMatchExtension xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                       <vehicleTrace xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FMCommonTypes.WCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                  <s:Latitude>2</s:Latitude>
                                  <s:Longitude>2</s:Longitude>
                                  <s:PositionGuid>577AF773-C7A8-4D65-82DA-37A15CC7611D</s:PositionGuid>
                       </vehicleTrace>
                 </HereRouteMatchExtension>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I am using following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    Latitude INT,
    Longitude INT, 
    PositionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO #test VALUES (1,1,NEWID())
INSERT INTO #test VALUES (2,2,NEWID())



WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS s, 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' AS a)
SELECT
( SELECT '1' AS  [a:Action/@mustUnderstand], 
 'http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension' AS [a:Action]
  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
),
'urn:uuid: some_messageID' AS 'a:MessageID',
( SELECT  'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous' AS [a:Address]
  FOR XML PATH ('a:ReplyTo'), TYPE
),
( SELECT '1' AS  [a:To/@mustUnderstand], 
 'ServiceURL' AS [a:To]
  FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
),
( SELECT '1' AS  [a:Action/@mustUnderstand]
FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE

),
(SELECT Latitude AS 's:Latitude',
       Longitude      AS 's:Longitude', 
       PositionGuid     AS 's:PositionGuid'
FROM #test
FOR XML PATH ('s:Body'),  TYPE
)

FOR XML RAW ('s:Header'), ELEMENTS, ROOT('s:Envelope')
```

There are 2 problems in the code i generated:

1) reference URLS are in every sub-section and I would like to have just once;

2) Body tag is inside the header and it is supposed to go straight after it...

How can I achieve that? This is the result I am getting:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: some_messageID</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" mustUnderstand="1">ServiceURL</a:To>
    <a:Action xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" mustUnderstand="1" />
    <s:Body xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <s:Latitude>1</s:Latitude>
      <s:Longitude>1</s:Longitude>
      <s:PositionGuid>34BD8E91-8567-4D58-A18E-61C3FBBF5C8F</s:PositionGuid>
    </s:Body>
  </s:Header>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: By "reference URLS", do you mean the `xmlns:a` etc namespace declarations?

Answer (score 2):

Try that

```
DECLARE  @test TABLE
(
    Latitude INT,
    Longitude INT, 
    PositionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1,1,NEWID());
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (2,2,NEWID());

    WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' AS s, 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' AS a)
    SELECT
        1 AS [s:Envelope/s:Header/a:Action/@s:mustUnderstand],
        'http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension' AS [s:Envelope/s:Header/a:Action],
        'urn:uuid: some_messageID' AS [s:Envelope/s:Header/a:MessageID],
        'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous' [s:Envelope/s:Header/a:ReplyTo/a:Address],
        1  as [s:Envelope/s:Header/To/@s:mustUnderstand],
        'ServiceURL' as  [s:Envelope/s:Header/To],
        Latitude as [s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Latitude],
        Longitude as  [s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Longitude],
        PositionGuid as  [s:Envelope/s:Body/s:PositionGuid]
        FROM @test
        FOR XML PATH('')
```

This way you produce two Envelope elements one for each row of the @table.

Edit:

I could not find a way to remove extra namespaces from child elements when generated with TYPE in a subquery with FOR XML PATH.

I came up with this solution which does not fully satisfy me:

```
DECLARE  @test TABLE
(
    Latitude INT,
    Longitude INT, 
    PositionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    x xml
)



DECLARE @x xml = 
'<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: some_messageID</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">ServiceURL</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
                <HereRouteMatchExtension xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                       <vehicleTrace xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FMCommonTypes.WCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                  <s:Latitude>2</s:Latitude>
                                  <s:Longitude>2</s:Longitude>
                                  <s:PositionGuid>577AF773-C7A8-4D65-82DA-37A15CC7611D</s:PositionGuid>
                       </vehicleTrace>
                 </HereRouteMatchExtension>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (10,10,NEWID(),@x);
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (20,20,NEWID(),@x);


UPDATE @test
SET x.modify('declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";declare default element  namespace "http://tempuri.org/";
replace value of (/s:Envelope/s:Body/HereRouteMatchExtension/vehicleTrace/s:Latitude/text())[1] with sql:column("Latitude")')
UPDATE @test
SET x.modify('declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";declare default element  namespace "http://tempuri.org/";
replace value of (/s:Envelope/s:Body/HereRouteMatchExtension/vehicleTrace/s:Longitude/text())[1] with sql:column("Longitude")')
UPDATE @test
SET x.modify('declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";declare default element  namespace "http://tempuri.org/";
replace value of (/s:Envelope/s:Body/HereRouteMatchExtension/vehicleTrace/s:PositionGuid/text())[1] with sql:column("PositionGuid")')


SELECT * FROM @test
```

and all at once with an insert:

```
DECLARE  @test TABLE
(
    Latitude INT,
    Longitude INT, 
    PositionGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    x xml
)



DECLARE @x xml = 
'<s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IGeocodeService/HereRouteMatchExtension</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid: some_messageID</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">ServiceURL</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
                <HereRouteMatchExtension xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                 </HereRouteMatchExtension>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'

INSERT INTO @test VALUES (10,10,NEWID(),@x);
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (20,20,NEWID(),@x);

UPDATE @test
SET x.modify('declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";declare default element  namespace "http://tempuri.org/";
insert  <vehicleTrace xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FMCommonTypes.WCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><s:Latitude>{sql:column("Latitude")}</s:Latitude>
        <s:Longitude>{sql:column("Longitude")}</s:Longitude>
        <s:PositionGuid>{sql:column("PositionGuid")}</s:PositionGuid></vehicleTrace> into (/s:Envelope/s:Body/HereRouteMatchExtension)[1]')


SELECT * FROM @test
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I asked. However I modified the question a bit, could you please take a look to the <body>...</body>. I've changed the code a bit there.

Comment: I think it can also be done with one insert instead of three replaces

Comment: With the second and third snippets of code it is not generated. It is already there. In the first occasion the code just replaces the values of the Longitude, Latitude and PositionGuid elemets. In the second, it inserts a constructed vehicleTrace element.

Comment: what I mean is that I modified the question little bit (inside <body> tag). Could you please show me how to do that?

Comment: the second and third are based on the modified question did you tried to run them?

Comment: In the first part you generate XML using SELECT statment. In the 2nd and the 3rd part you are just setting it as a string. I need to generate this automatically using SELECT statement.

Comment: The template is assigned as a string but then it is modified with xquery to contain the right values

Comment: I see. But is there any chance to generate everything with SELECT statement?